# Why does dataframe df < 1 return True for any column that contains even a single str value?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, logical-operators

I did some logical check for my DataFrame which is as simple as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1' : [2, 'A', 3],
                   'c2' : [4, 5, 1]})
```

and I did this:

```
df <= 1
```

Here is the output:

```
     c1     c2
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True   True
```

You can see that all checking in column c1 returned True, even including the checking for 'A', which is something I don't know why, cause I thought 'A' cannot be compared with 1 and should raise an error. Also, 2 and 3 in column c1 are apparently not <= 1.

Then I tried :

```
df > 1
```

And I got:

```
     c1     c2
0  True   True
1  True   True
2  True  False
```

All the checking results fro column c1 still remain True. How could something be <= 1 and > 1 simultaneously? Can somebody help me with this?
Thx!!!

Comment: Because Python evaluates strings differently to integers. Empty strings evaluate as False, any other string is True.

Comment: This gives `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: Remove the 'A' and it will work just fine